Insert a table of contents in a Word document generated using an Excel macro
I'm trying to take data from an Excel sheet and put it into plain English sentences in a report generated in one click plus a little case-by-case cleaning up.
I have no problems doing this:
Sub formGeneration()
    Dim objWord
    Dim objDoc
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet
    
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
    Set sht1 = Worksheets("Raw Data Sheet 1")

    With objWord

        .Visible = True
        .Activate

        With .Selection

            'pretend I define all my text and document formatting here
            .typetext("The first value is ")
            .typetext(.sht1.Range("A1").Text)
            .typetext(".")
            .typeparagraph

            'etc etc etc for other values from the sheet
        End With
    End With
End Sub

I tried to insert a table of contents object using the syntax from the documentation on microsoft.com.
Their example is supposed to "build a table of contents from all paragraphs styled as Heading 1, Heading 2, or Heading 3.".
I added a range variable at the top like the example.
I tried it both inside and outside the Sub, the with objWord, and the with .Selection blocks.
I tried both assigning the value of the variable in the Dim statement and doing a Dim myRange followed by a Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0).
Dim myRange = Range '(have also tried Word.Range)

Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=0, End:=100000000) '(by the way, how do I set the end of the range to the bottom of the document?)

'this is microsoft's example copied verbatim but it breaks when pasted anywhere in my code 
ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents.Add Range:=myRange, _ 
 UseFields:=False, UseHeadingStyles:=True, _ 
 LowerHeadingLevel:=3, _ 
 UpperHeadingLevel:=1

My goal is to use ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents(1).Update at the end to grab all of the headings I've put in. The headings themselves are formatted and inserted just fine.
I get errors such as a generic "Syntax error" (if I try to just use Range:=(some argument) next to the TablesOfContents.Add, or "object required" if I try to say Range:=myRange as in Microsoft's example, as well as other ones I haven't been able to replicate in a little while now.
I must be defining my range variable in the wrong place and VBA is parsing it as an Excel Range and not a Word Range. I've gotten "this object doesn't support this method".
I'm referencing the Word object library.

Maybe: Dim myRange As Range or Dim myRange As Object or just Dim myRange same as you did with objWord and objDoc.

In .typetext(.sht1.Range("A1").Text) the .sht references the with block.  You probably mean to reference the Excel object, ie use sht. ... without the dot

@chrisneilsen that was actually just a typo and not how I've used that in my actual project, but probably a mistake I would've made at some point considering I didn't catch it here, so thank you for the heads up!

Note: Programming with inter-operable Office applications becomes easier when using early binding due to VBE's IntelliSense autocomplete feature.

Understanding the distinction between late and early binding is crucial when attempting to utilize Excel VBA code to manipulate Word.

Microsoft documentation:

Early and Late Binding (Visual Basic)


Late binding is used in your first snippet. Dim myRange As Range doesn't work. Excel VBA think it as Dim myRange As Excel.Range. Use Dim myRange As Object in your code.

The parent object of Word.Selection is Word.Application instead of Word.Document.

ActiveDocument is an object of Word, Excel VBA doesn't know it. The right way to refer active document is using objWord.ActiveDocument.


Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim objWord As Object ' Word.Application
    Dim objDoc As Object ' Word.Document
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet
    Dim myRange As Object ' Word.Range
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
    With objWord
        .Visible = True
        ' your code to add contents with styles
        Call InsertSampleText(objWord)
     End With
     With objDoc
        Set myRange = .Range(Start:=0, End:=0)
        .TablesOfContents.Add Range:=myRange, _
            UseFields:=False, UseHeadingStyles:=True, _
            LowerHeadingLevel:=3, _
            UpperHeadingLevel:=1
    End With
End Sub

Sub InsertSampleText(objWord) ' for testing
    With objWord
        .Selection.TypeText Text:="Heading1"
        .Selection.Style = .ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1")
        .Selection.TypeParagraph
        .Selection.TypeText Text:="Heading2"
        .Selection.Style = .ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 2")
        .Selection.TypeParagraph
        .Selection.TypeText Text:="Heading3"
        .Selection.Style = .ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 3")
    End With
End Sub



An alternative link for Early vs Late Binding. TLDR: Using late binding is a bad idea. Don't do it.
